# Adding image to HStack influences spacing

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var isShowingImage = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Lorem ipsum").fontWeight(.bold).lineLimit(1).border(Color.green)
                if isShowingImage {
                    Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 16, height: 16).border(Color.blue)
                }
            }.border(Color.black)
            Text("Ad veritatis totam asperiores est error. Dolore perspiciatis unde aut.").lineLimit(1).border(Color.purple)
            Text("Dolorem illum").font(.footnote).border(Color.red)
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HStack {
            ContentView()
            ContentView(isShowingImage: false)
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

If `isShowingImage` is true, then the image appears. This also adds padding between the first `HStack` and the text "Ad veritatis". If no image is shown, then there's no padding. What causes the padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, that there's such a thing as default spacing. If you leave stack spacing nil, then the stack will choose a default spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what causes it, but if you use `VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0)` the space disappears

Comment: Yeah I found that out myself, but I'm not looking for a workaround but rather the cause. Thanks for replying though.